# Where to implement Entity Framework database transactions in modern web applications?

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

Let’s assume that the primary components in your application are an Angular client, which calls an ASP.NET Web API, which uses Entity Framework to perform CRUD operations on your database. So, for example, in your API controllers, the Post (Add) method adds a new entity to the database context and then commits it to the database by calling the Entity Framework SaveChanges method.

This works fine when only one record needs to be added to the database at a time.

But, what if, for example, you want to add several records of different entity types to your database in one transaction? Where do you implement the Database.BeginTransaction and Database.CommitTransaction/RollbackTransaction? If you add a service layer to accomplish this, then what does the Angular client call?

---

**PLEASE SEE BELOW FOR FURTHER DETAIL AND QUESTIONS.**

I want to provide more detail about my current approach to solving this problem and ask the following questions:

**(1) Is this a good approach, or is there a better way?**

**(2) My approach does not port to .NET Core, since .NET Core does not support OData yet (see https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/229). Any thoughts or ideas about this?**

I have stated the problems that I faced and the solutions that I chose below. I will use a simple scenario where a customer is placing an order for several items – so, there is one Order record with several OrderDetail records. The Order record and associated OrderDetail records must be committed to the database in a single transaction.

**Problem #1:** What is the best way to send the Order and OrderDetail records from the Angular client to the ASP.NET Web API?

**Solution #1:** I decided to use OData batching, so that I could send all the records in one POST. I am using the datajs library to perform the batching (https://www.nuget.org/packages/datajs).

**Problem #2:** How do I wrap a single transaction around the Order and OrderDetail records?

**Solution #2:** I set up an OData batch endpoint in my Web API, which involved the following:

(1) In the client, configure a batch request route.

```
// Configure the batch request route.
config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute(
    routeName: "batch",
    routePrefix: "batch",
    model: builder.GetEdmModel(),
    pathHandler: new DefaultODataPathHandler(),
    routingConventions: conventions,
    batchHandler: new TransactionalBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
}
```

(2) In the Web API, implement a custom batch handler, which wraps a database transaction around the given OData batch. The batch handler starts the transaction, calls the appropriate ODataController to perform the CRUD operation, and then commits/rolls back the transaction, depending on the results.

```
/// <summary>
/// Custom batch handler specialized to execute batch changeset in OData $batch requests with transactions.
/// The requests will be executed in the order they arrive, that means that the client is responsible for
/// correctly ordering the operations to satisfy referential constraints.
/// </summary>
public class TransactionalBatchHandler : DefaultODataBatchHandler
{
    public TransactionalBatchHandler(HttpServer httpServer)
        : base(httpServer)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the batch request and wraps the execution of the whole changeset within a transaction.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="requests">The <see cref="ODataBatchRequestItem"/> instances of this batch request.</param>
    /// <param name="cancellation">The <see cref="CancellationToken"/> associated with the request.</param>
    /// <returns>The list of responses associated with the batch request.</returns>
    public async override Task<IList<ODataBatchResponseItem>> ExecuteRequestMessagesAsync(
        IEnumerable<ODataBatchRequestItem> requests,
        CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        if (requests == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("requests");
        }

        IList<ODataBatchResponseItem> responses = new List<ODataBatchResponseItem>();
        try
        {
            foreach (ODataBatchRequestItem request in requests)
            {
                OperationRequestItem operation = request as OperationRequestItem;
                if (operation != null)
                {
                    responses.Add(await request.SendRequestAsync(Invoker, cancellation));
                }
                else
                {
                    await ExecuteChangeSet((ChangeSetRequestItem)request, responses, cancellation);
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            foreach (ODataBatchResponseItem response in responses)
            {
                if (response != null)
                {
                    response.Dispose();
                }
            }
            throw;
        }

        return responses;
    }

    private async Task ExecuteChangeSet(
        ChangeSetRequestItem changeSet,
        IList<ODataBatchResponseItem> responses,
        CancellationToken cancellation)
    {
        ChangeSetResponseItem changeSetResponse;

        // Since IUnitOfWorkAsync is a singleton (Unity PerRequestLifetimeManager) used by all our ODataControllers,
        // we simply need to get a reference to it and use it for managing transactions. The ODataControllers
        // will perform IUnitOfWorkAsync.SaveChanges(), but the changes won't get committed to the DB until the
        // IUnitOfWorkAsync.Commit() is performed (in the code directly below).

        var unitOfWorkAsync = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetService(typeof(IUnitOfWorkAsync)) as IUnitOfWorkAsync;

        unitOfWorkAsync.BeginTransaction();

        // This sends each request in the changeSet to the appropriate ODataController.
        changeSetResponse = (ChangeSetResponseItem)await changeSet.SendRequestAsync(Invoker, cancellation);

        responses.Add(changeSetResponse);

        if (changeSetResponse.Responses.All(r => r.IsSuccessStatusCode))
        {
            unitOfWorkAsync.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            unitOfWorkAsync.Rollback();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: "IUnitOfWorkAsync is a singleton". That's the root of all evil. Start a UoW, commit it, and dispose it after the request.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to implement Database.BeginTransaction and Database.CommitTransaction/RollbackTransaction if you are using Entity Framework. Entity Framework implements UnitOfWork. The only thing that you should care about is to work with a different instance of DbContext for every web request, but exaclty 1 instance for 1 request and call SaveChanges only 1 time when you made all the changes you need.

In case of any Exception during SaveChanges all the changes will be rolled back.

The angular client should not care about this, it only sends the data and checks if everything was fine.

This is very easy to do if you use an IoC framework, like Unity and let your DbContext injected in your Controller or Service.

In this case you should use the following settings (if you use Unity):

```
container.RegisterType<DbContext, YourDbContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), ...);
```

Then you can do this if you want to use it in a Controller:

```
public class YourController : Controller
{
    private YourDbContext _db;

    public YourController(DbContext context)
    {
        _db = context;
    }
...
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Please see the additional section I added and let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

No need to over-complicate things. Add the code to the WebApi project. Pass around your Transaction object and re-use it. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn456843(v=vs.113).aspx for an example.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Please see the additional section I added and let me know what you think.